# Android studio avd error 'invalid option --enable whpx'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

What is this error ?
I want  add a device in android studio but i get this error: 'invalid option --enable whpx'

Comment: Hello 
I want  add a device in android studio but i get this error: 
'invalid option --enable whpx'
What is this error ????
What is that solution????

And

When i install genymotion plugin , that not show genymotion icon in toolbar .
But exist in plugin list ! 

How can i fix it?
 
Tnx

Comment: Welcome to SO. About the genymotion plugin, sounds like a bug to me too. Anyways, seems like you added '`invalid option --enable whpx` in gradle or anywhere in your project which you should paste the logcat to check where that is.